# Delphi TIdHttpServer: can all trafic be logged?

Tags: http, delphi, indy

I am writing an HTTP server with a TIdHttpServer and I want to log all trafic (full HTTP requests) correctly.  I found several similar topics for this, but in none of them I can find a guarantee whether the response was actually sent or not.
I know an exception will be triggered in Indy in `function TIdCustomHTTPServer.DoExecute(AContext:TIdContext): boolean;` if the response could not be sent, but that exception could also have happened AFTER the response was sent (and TIdHttpServer is waiting for a next command).
Is there a way to know whether the command was actually sent or not?

In the example below I managed to log incoming messages correctly, but I have not found a correct way to detect if the response was sent or not.

```
procedure TfmMain.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  //log the incoming request
  Log(getIdConnPeerAsStr(AContext) {IP:port} + (ARequestInfo.RawHTTPCommand + ARequestInfo.RawHeaders.Text));

  //Prepare the response
  AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/html';
  AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8';
  AResponseInfo.ContentText := '<html><body>Hello</body></html>';

  //How to log the output(AResponseInfo) here?  It is too soon because the sending of the packet has not yet occurred
end;
```

Comment: Indy includes TIdIntercept* classes which can be used to log low-level data flow, just create one and assign it to the intercept property of the server, for example TIdInterceptSimLog (logs to a file)

Comment: There are also several `TIdLog...` components which are also intercepts. But, in any case, note that intercepts are assigned per-connection, and while the server does have an `Intercept` property to help automate the creation of client connection intercepts, most of the intercept components (including `TIdInterceptSimLog`) do not actually implement server-side support, so they cannot be used with the server's `Intercept` property. They would have to instead be created and assigned manually to the `AContext.Connection.Intercept` property in the server's `OnConnect` event at runtime.